# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type invalid block : ' in /home/website/www/app/Mage.php:594

Tags: magento-1.7, category, category-products, redirect-url

When I click on `category` like example-category page magento rise following error.
In this category have only one `product` like : example-product.

Catogary URL : `https://www.website.com/main-category/example-category.html` this redirect to `https://www.website.com/main-category/example-category/example-product.html` but its give `302 status` and redirect to homepage `https://www.website.com`

Another category have multiple products its work fine but above category page not working propely

After that its give following error.

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Type de bloc no...')
#1 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'category.produc...')
#3 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'category.produc...')
#4 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(146): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/website/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/website/www/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/website/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('french', 'store')
#14 {main}
2016-06-25T05:42:24+00:00 ERR (3):
```

I tried clear Cache and Reindexing.
What is wrong for this issue in **Magento 1.7.0.2**.

Comment: Clear the Cache, this should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it and also indexing.